# How to store my map in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, dictionary, mapping

I'm a C newbie.

I want to my string "`aaaabbbbbbb`" to a kind of map

```
array1[0][0] = (a,4)
array1[1][0] = (b,7)
```

and compare this string "4444bbbbbbb" and make the other map and find same element and count between two maps

```
array2[0][1] = (b,7)
array2[1][1] = (4,4)
```

so we can find `array1[1][0] == array2[0][1]`

I want to make feature like that

```
1. "aaaabbbbb" => total element = 2
2. "aaaabbbbb" => map (a : 4, b : 5)
3. "4444bbbbb", "4433bbbbb" => (4 : 4, b : 5) , (4 : 2, 3 : 3, b : 5) -> same element with same count
```

is there any example for me? please help me.

Comment: I don't understand your question (your notation is not C code, and is not common enough to be understood). Why use strings if you are concerned with associations? Did you consider other data structures (hash-tables)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be to

1. Find the longest common subsequence of both strings (see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence)
2. Remove this subsequence from both strings
3. Goto 1